background color not displaying whie using hex code
The following code generates blue text boxes when OptionOne or OptionTwo is selected. For example, when the Show Options button is clicked, a blue text box appears on the left side and then I can enter row and column values and hit the calculate button to figure out the cell number where it needs to be moved using the Move Text Content! button.
The problem I'm facing is related to the background color. I have a brown color defined in hex code as follows and others are mentioned as it is. I plan on replacing all colors with hex code if this works. While reading this, it looks like what I'm trying to achieve is not possible. Is there any other workaround for the same ?
<select id="lineupColors">
       <option value="-">select</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="orange">Orange</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="purple">Purple</option>
      <option value="#7c4700">Brown</option>
      <option value="black">Black</option>
      <option value="magenta">Magenta</option>
    </select>

However, it doesn't work when I use the hex code in the following line    $('.color-'+selectedColor).css('background-color',selectedColor);
Here is my code snippet:


/*

Requires jquery + UI

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js

*/

$('[name="optionSelection"]').change(function () {
      //clean up the divs inside div with id phrase
    $("#phrase").empty();
  });
let selectedColor;
  function showOptions() {
  
    console.log($("#optionSelection").val());
    selectedColor = $('#lineupColors').val();
    var html;
    if ($("#optionSelection").val() == 1) {
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         
            html = "<div data-id="+i+"><span class='words' style='color:black;background-color:white'  data-id="+i+">OptionOne#"+i+"</span></div>";
            $("#phrase").append(html);
      }
      
    }
    else {
      for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
         
        html = "<div data-id="+j+"><span class='words'  style='color:black;background-color:white' data-id="+j+">OptionTwo#"+j+"</span></div>";
       $("#phrase").append(html);
    }
   // $("#phrase").append(html);
  }
}


  $(".words").draggable({
    revert: function (event, ui) {
      var bRevertingPhrase = this.closest("#drop-em");

      if (!bRevertingPhrase.length) {
        var phraseID = $(this).data("id");
        var phraseHomeID = $(this).parent().data("id");

        //If the child and parent ids don't match, we move the child to the correct parent
        if (phraseID !== phraseHomeID) {
          var correctCell = $("#phrase").find(
            "div[data-id='" + phraseID + "']"
          );
          correctCell.prepend(this);
        }
      }
      return !event;
    },
  });
  $("#drop-em > div").droppable({
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable)
        .detach()
        .css({ top: 0, left: 0 })
        .appendTo($(this).find(".content:empty"));
      //$("#move-text").addClass("disabled");
    },
  });
  $("#phrase > div").droppable({
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).prependTo(this);
    },
  });

  const myButton = document.querySelector("#move-text");
  myButton.addEventListener(
    "click",
    () => {
      fill();
    },
   /* {
      once: true,
    }*/
  );

  var reOrder = [];
  function fill() {
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll("#phrase > div > span");
    var newLoc = "";
    //myButton.classList.add("disabled");

    cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
      newLoc = document.querySelector(
        ".item:nth-child(" + reOrder[index + startPos - 1] + ") .content "
      );
      newLoc.append(cell);
      newLoc.classList.add("moved");
       newLoc.classList.add("color-"+selectedColor);
       console.log("Test with codes");
       console.log(selectedColor);
      $('.color-'+selectedColor).css('background-color',selectedColor);
      
    });
  }
  function reArrange() {
    var limit1 = 85;
    var limit2 = 91;

    for (let loop = 0; loop < 8; loop++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        reOrder.push(limit1 + i);
      }
      limit1 = limit1 - 12;
    }
    for (let loop = 0; loop < 8; loop++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        reOrder.push(limit2 + j);
      }
      limit2 = limit2 - 12;
    }
  }
  reArrange();

  /* get cell number */

  const myRow = document.querySelector("#inp1");
  const myCol = document.querySelector("#inp2");
  var startPos = 0;
  const myCalculateButton = document.querySelector("#calculate");
  const myAnswer = document.querySelector("#cellnum");
  myCalculateButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var rowNumber = myRow.value.toUpperCase();
    var colNumber = myCol.value;
    var result = 0;
    switch (rowNumber) {
      case "A":
        rowNumber = 42;
        break;
      case "B":
        rowNumber = 36;
        break;
      case "C":
        rowNumber = 30;
        break;
      case "D":
        rowNumber = 24;
        break;
      case "E":
        rowNumber = 18;
        break;
      case "F":
        rowNumber = 12;
        break;
      case "G":
        rowNumber = 6;
        break;
      case "H":
        rowNumber = 0;
        break;
    }

    if (colNumber < 7) {
      result = rowNumber + parseInt(colNumber);
    } else {
      result = rowNumber + 42 + parseInt(colNumber);
    }
    myAnswer.innerHTML = result;
    startPos = result;
  });
  
 
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  body {
    counter-reset: columnCount 1 alphaCount cellCount;
  }
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .wrap {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 220px;
  }

  .grid {
    margin: auto;
    display: grid;
    flex: 1 0 0;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
  }

  .item {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    counter-increment: columnCount;
    min-width: 0;
    transition: background 1s ease;
  }
  .item:nth-of-type(12n + 1) {
    counter-increment: alphaCount;
  }
  .item:nth-of-type(12n + 1)::before {
    content: counter(alphaCount, upper-alpha);
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -1.75rem;
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .item:nth-of-type(n + 13)::after {
    display: none;
  }
  .item::after {
    content: counter(columnCount);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: -1.75rem;
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #000;
    padding: 1rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    counter-increment: cellCount;
  }

  .words {
    cursor: move;
    transition: padding 0.5s ease;
   }
     
  .content:has(.ui-draggable-dragging) {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .ui-droppable-active .content {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .words.ui-draggable-dragging {
    background: blue;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 999;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #phrase {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 1rem 0 0.5rem;
  }
  #phrase > div {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #007bff;
    border: 2px solid #007bff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  #phrase > div:empty {
    background: #fff;
    border-style: dashed;
    padding: 0px 25px;
    min-height: 30px;
  }

  .moved {
    animation: fade 3s ease;
  }
  @keyframes fade {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
      background: red;
    }
  }

  .item .content::before {
    content: counter(cellCount);
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    font-size: smaller;
    color: #666;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: white;
    width: 1.2rem;
    height: 1, 2rem;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  }

  #move-text.disabled {
    cursor: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  #phrase:has(.ui-droppable-active) {
    overflow: visible;
  }

  input,
  button,
  label,
  p.target {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0.4rem;
    color: #000;
  }
  p.target {
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
  }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- You'd need to set up something different for touch devices though -->

  <h1>Move testings</h1>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>
      <label for="optionSelection">Select options</label>
      <select name="optionSelection" id="optionSelection">
        <option value="1">OptionOne</option>
        <option value="2">OptionTwo</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="lineupColors">Colors:<br /></label>
    <select id="lineupColors">
       <option value="-">select</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="orange">Orange</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="purple">Purple</option>
      <option value="#7c4700">Brown</option>
      <option value="black">Black</option>
      <option value="magenta">Magenta</option>
    </select>
  </div>
    <div>
      <button id="showOptions" onclick="showOptions()" type="button">
        Show Options
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="inp1">Enter a row A - H</label>
      <input id="inp1" placeholder="Enter Row" />
      <label for="inp2">Enter a column 1 - 12</label>
      <input id="inp2" placeholder="Enter Column" />
      <button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
      <p class="target">The cell number is <b id="cellnum">?</b></p>
      <button id="move-text" type="button">Move Text Content!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="phrase">
      <!-- remove whitespace from  inside div html and then we can use :empty in css to change background -->
      <!-- <div data-id="1"><span class="words" data-id="1">H1 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="2"><span class="words" data-id="2">H2 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="3"><span class="words" data-id="3">H3 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="4"><span class="words" data-id="4">H4 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="5"><span class="words" data-id="5">H5 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="6"><span class="words" data-id="6">H6 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="7"><span class="words" data-id="7">G1 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="8"><span class="words" data-id="8">G2 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="9"><span class="words" data-id="9">G3 text</span></div>
      <div data-id="10"><span class="words" data-id="10">G4 text</span></div> -->
    </div>

    <div id="drop-em" class="grid">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <!-- must have no spaces inside .content -->
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




your code snippet doesn't seem to do anything with any colours

It works. See this image: https://i.sstatic.net/9EDuz.png

yeah, you have to select a column and row, hit calculate, select a colour, click show options, click move text (so obvious, right) ... then you can see it fail because there is no such class as color-#7c4700 - or maybe because you don't set the background-color style ... hard to say, the code is hard to read

the issue is with $('.color-'+selectedColor) ... since .color-#7c4700 is not a valid selector

So what do you think would be the fix? Sorry for not making the overall process not obvious

Other option I am thinking is to just store every color in the database and have each color correspond to an id field from the database and then use it to populate the colors.

fix like: newLoc.classList.add("color-"+selectedColor.replace('#', '')); and then $('.color-'+selectedColor.replace('#', '')).css('background-color',selectedColor);

Thanks or the way it is suggested in the answer to use CSS escape.

This is because when you have # in your CSS selector query, it is querying for ID of the elements instead. When you run the following line:
$('.color-#7c4700');

Jquery is actually requesting for elements with:

class: color-
id: 7c4700

Edit after comment by @Jaromanda X: It seems like jQuery is more lax when querying for elements. document.querySelector will instantly throw error when you attempt to query .color-#7c4700.

This can can be illustrated in the example below


$('.color-#7c4700').css('background-color', '#7c4700');
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- You are not selecting this -->
<div class="color-#7c4700">class=color-#7c4700</div>

<!-- You are selecting this instead! -->
<div id="7c4700" class="color-">id=7c4700 class=color-</div>




Solution
In order to fix this, you can consider using CSS.escape that should escape the # character for you, in order to be used in selector successfully:


$('.color-' + CSS.escape('#7c4700')).css('background-color', '#7c4700');
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- You are now selecting this :) -->
<div class="color-#7c4700">class=color-#7c4700</div>

<!-- And not this -->
<div id="7c4700" class="color-">id=7c4700 class=color-</div>




Based on the specifications, nearly all characters are allowed in a CSS class name, and # is also valid. However, you need to be careful to escape it when performing selector query as it might represent other selector.

.color-#7c4700 is actually an INVALID CSS selector ... sure, it may be a valid jQuery selector, but it's never a valid CSS selector :p

@JaromandaX Thanks for the advice! I am now trying to understand more what jQuery is doing behind the scene...

what jQuery is doing behind the scene - besides subverting web standards :p
